# buttonTitleAtIndex not working with iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I just finished updating an app for support for iPhone 5 and iOS6 and I found an odd bug.

in iOS5 this code works fine, but on every iOS6 device nothing happens when the buttons are pressed and the debugger sees buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex as an unknown method. I made a work around using the actual buttonIndex number instead of the string, but I'm confused why this would happen, as I know of no reason why support for this should change with iOS6.

```
if([actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] == @"Email to a friend") {
        NSLog(@"Email");
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }

    else if ([actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] == @"Add to Favorites")                   {
        NSLog(@"favorites");
        [self addFavorite];
    }
    else if ([actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] == @"Post to Facebook") {
        NSLog(@"Facebook");
        [self shareOnFacebook];
    }
    else if ([actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] == @"Tweet this") {
        NSLog(@"tweet");
        [self tweet];
    }
```

Comment: Go through your entire app and find every use of `==` for comparing strings and other objects. Replace every use with an appropriate `isEqual:` method call. You should only use `==` to compare basic types like `int`, `float`, `NSInteger`, etc.

Comment: This change worked and the new xcode update now has an alert for this issue, naturally only right after I find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare Objective-C objects by address. `==` will not work the way you want it to. That it was working for you on iOS 5 was a quirk only, and could change with a simple recompile.

You must use `-isEqual:` to compare two objects:

```
if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqual:@"Email to a friend"]) {
    ...
}
```

A better approach would be to compare the button index to a known list (an `enum` for instance, however. This will make localization easier and prevent bugs if you happen to rename a button later.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now.

Also in case you wanted to know, the new update of xcode has a new alert about this issue.

Comment: What?! Of course you can compare objects in Objective C for **identity**, that is what `==` does! The quirk here is that in previous versions of iOS `buttonTitleAtIndex` was returning the _very same_ NSString you gave it and now it returns a different object. Admittedly apples never promised you can use it as a token. But yes, the fix is to use `isEqualToString` now for `buttonTitleAtIndex`

Comment: No, you can't. You can compare object *pointers* with the `==` operator. Two objects cannot meaningfully be tested for equality with `==`, only identity.

Answer (score 2):

The following prints correct title for me:

```
NSLog(@"TITLE: %@", [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex: buttonIndex]);
```

For comparison, do like following:

```
[[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex: buttonIndex] isEqualToString: @"Email to a friend"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are not using isEqualToString. "==" is not really doing a string comparison, it's simply comparing the same spot in memory, which may be the reason it's failing in iOS 6.